# JavaScript Array Search Method

Tags: arrays, search

I'm currently engaged in self-learning through W3Schools, and I came across the following code:

```
const temp = [27, 28, 30, 40, 42, 35, 30];
let high = temp.findLast(x => x > 40);
```

I find the second line, specifically **(x => x > 40)**, challenging to grasp at my current stage of learning. It's possible that this concept will be explained in more detail in later chapters. Could someone please shed light on what this code does and how the **(x => x > 40)** part works? I have a basic understanding that it involves an arrow function.

I haven't attempted anything yet, as I'm still in the learning phase and have a rough idea that this is an arrow function.

Comment: Look up “first class functions” and “fat arrow functions” and read the MDN documentation on findLast

Answer (score 0):

`x => x > 40`

**it's an arrow function that takes an element of the array and returns `=>` whether it's greater than 40 or not.**

**in more details:**

findLast method rules:

- The `findLast()` method returns the value of the last element that
  passes a test.
- The `findLast()` method executes a function for each array element.
- The `findLast()` method returns undefined if no elements are found.

look at its syntax:

```
array.findLast(function(currentValue, index, arr),thisValue)
```

don't worry, all you have to know: **it takes a function as a parameter**

this `parameter function` is supposed to take current element value and make a test that return a boolean value.

---

Now, let's sum up.

`findLast` iterates over its elements and execute the parameter function for every element, the element which satisfies the condition within the parameter function is returned.

Answer (score -1):

Code:

```
const temp = [27, 28, 30, 40, 42, 35, 30];
let high = temp.findLast(x => x > 40);
```

1. You created an array called `temp` containing 7 elements within it, each element has values ​​of type number;
2. In the second line there is the creation of a variable that will later receive a single number that is the result of the following code sentence `temp.findLast(x => x > 40)`;
3. `temp.findLast()` will traverse the `temp` array in **reverse order**
   (starting from 30, 35... up to 27) and **will return the first element
   tested that satisfy the `true`** condition of the callback **x => x > 40**
   passed by parameter;

**Observation/Test**:

a) Test by adding an element with the value 45 at the beginning of the array, you will see that `high` will remain 42 because 42 is the **first element found by findLast() in the reverse order that returned 'true' by the callback**.

b) The iteration of the findLast function is interrupted as soon as it receives the first number greater than or equal to 40 in reverse order, that is, there will no longer be any processing resources being used;

c) If there is no `true` condition returned by **callback**, this means that `findLast(x => x > 40)` will go through the `temp` array completely and will return `undefined` as it does not contain any number that satisfies the true condition of **callback**

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findLast

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).